# Unable to comment out code involving multiline strings

Tags: python

Basically I am curious about why this throws a syntax error and what is the pythonic way to 'comment out' portions of my code that I am not using, for example during a debugging session.

```
'''
def foo():
        '''does nothing'''
'''
```

Comment: Comments are indicated by a `#` at the beginning of the line. There is no multiline comment in Python. Your IDE or text editor may have a comment toggling facility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use triple double quotes to comment out triple single quotes:

```
"""
def foo():
    '''does nothing'''
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is interpreting your code like this:

First comment:

```
'''
def foo():
        '''
```

Second comment:

```
    '''
'''
```

Therefore, the "does nothing" is outside the comment, and python tries to interpret it, but the syntax is invalid, so it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way is to understand the difference between a multi-line string and a comment and use them appropriately.

Python does *not* have multi-line comments, but many python aware editors and IDE's have ways to automatically comment out selected multiple lines, (and the reverse). You might want to search for that useful functionality.